# How to Call Mandrill and iTextSharp dll from windows services?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll, mandrill

I developed a windows service application using c# to send mail with pdf attachment , So i am using **Mandrill** dll for send bulk mails and **iTextSharp** dll for convert PDF ..

> It working fine while run as windows application..

But in Windows service it throws an exception. Even i add the reference those dll to windows service application

Please suggest how integrate those dll to windows service..

Thanks in Advance..
Kartik

Comment: Perhaps you should focus on fixing the actual exception, please include it in your post. Why are you convinced it is related to Madrill and/or iTextSharp? And how would it be related to *both*?

Comment: @Paul-Jan Because it through the exception like "   at Mandrill.MandrillApi.SendMessage(EmailMessage message, String templateName, IEnumerable`1 templateContents, Nullable`1 send_at, Boolean async) in c:\Users\vts\Desktop\WS\Mandrill-dotnet-master\src\Mandrill\Messages.cs:line 332"

Comment: Is it possible to add the third party dll to windows service